# replace string with multiple overwrite string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like `const str = "string lower and lower case"`

above string should be like "string **lower** and **lower case**"

it's lower and lower case should be bold.

Comment: A regular expression alone won't produce bold text. Can you precise your question ?

Comment: There is no difference between a bold letter and a regular letter.  Is this an HTML question?

Comment: if it's intended to be used in html `str.replace(/(lower (case)?)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in HTML using Regular Expressions:

```html
<div id="text"></div>
<script>
  var str = "string lower and lower case"; // You can't have const.
  text.innerHTML = str.replace(/(lower (case)?)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
</script>
```

Comment: I have little bit issue here, i want match word.
like, var str = "string lower and newlowerstring".
then string should be like:  "string <strong>lower</strong> and newlowerstring".
and above logic i got "string <strong>lower</lower> and new<strong>lower</strong>string"